# gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 0] Error when gcloud app deploy

Tags: python, gcloud

Using Windows terminal
error after creating executable in /env/bin/python
I have no idea for this error
I just deploy an hello_world_django

Error

```
Step #1: Using base prefix '/opt/python3.6'
Step #1: New python executable in /env/bin/python3.6
Step #1: Also creating executable in /env/bin/python
Step #1: Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

[Errno 0] Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 844, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 756, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 87, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 593, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 392, in Deploy
    flex_image_build_option)
    ...
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\cloudbuild\logs.py", line 156, in _PrintLogLine
    self.out.Print(text)
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\log.py", line 168, in Print
    self._Write(message + '\n')
  File "\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\log.py", line 193, in _Write
    self.__stream_wrapper.stream.write(stream_msg)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: Do not add SOLVED in the title, in SO it is not enough to mark an answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/68292663). The most likely cause of this error is a regression in the Windows console API, specifically when blocking events are triggered by text selection in the console:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36630#issuecomment-350063413
- https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/40

If this is the cause, there is no fix until Microsoft ships an update for Windows in the spring.
Terminals embedded in VScode are more likely to have this issue as the IDE is doing a bunch of stuff to capture output from the console behind the scenes.

Possible workarounds are to not use the embedded terminal, and to make sure not to touch the terminal while it is printing. There is also a mention of "legacy terminal mode" which seems to fix the issue, but can break newer CLI tools—we don't know right now whether gcloud works successfully in legacy terminal mode.

Comment: Thank you!! I solve this problem by using cloud shell!